# Changing color of seaborn plot line

Tags: python, colors, seaborn

I can't change the color of a 2d line in seaborn.
I have 2 lines in my plot and I want to assign different colors for both of them.

```py
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
data = pd.DataFrame(result_prices, columns=['Size percentage increase'])
data2 = pd.DataFrame(result_sizes, columns=['Size percentage increase'])
sns_plot = sns.lineplot(data=data, color='red', linewidth=2.5)
sns_plot = sns.lineplot(data=data2, linewidth=2.5)
sns_plot.figure.savefig("size_percentage_increase.png")
```

But `color='red'` does not change the color, why?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You have a couple of options here. You can tweak your use of the `color` parameter, or you can use the `palette` parameter.

---

### `palette`

Using `palette` would arguably be the cleaner approach. Ideally, you would make only one call to `lineplot` when using `palette`--with the use of `hue` parameter:

```
np.random.seed(42)
y0 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(20), columns=['value'])
y1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(20), columns=['value'])
y = pd.concat([y0, y1], axis=0, keys=['y0', 'y1']).reset_index()
y = y.rename(columns={'level_0': 'group', 'level_1': 'x'})

sns.lineplot(data=y, x='x', y='value', hue='group', palette=['r', 'g'], linewidth=2.5)
```

[image]

But you could call `lineplot` for each line similar  to how you did in your  post:

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
data = pd.DataFrame(result_prices, columns=['Size percentage increase'])
data2 = pd.DataFrame(result_sizes, columns=['Size percentage increase'])
sns_plot = sns.lineplot(data=data, palette=['red'], linewidth=2.5)
sns_plot = sns.lineplot(data=data2, linewidth=2.5)
sns_plot.figure.savefig("size_percentage_increase.png")
```

---

### `color`

Using the `color` parameter only appears to work with Series objects. This
would be most useful when plotting a single line, rather than when coloring multiple lines in a plot.

Since your dataframes seem to only be one column, you could (A) convert them to Series objects or (B) define `x` and `y` parameters when calling `lineplot`.

[Documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) has an example toward the end.

##### A) Convert to Series

Using your code, it would look something like:

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
data = pd.Series(result_prices)
data2 = pd.Series(result_sizes)
sns_plot = sns.lineplot(data=data, color='red', linewidth=2.5)
sns_plot = sns.lineplot(data=data2, linewidth=2.5)
sns_plot.figure.savefig("size_percentage_increase.png")
```

As a minimal example:

```
np.random.seed(42)
y0 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(20), columns=['value'])
y1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(20), columns=['value'])
sns.lineplot(data=y0['value'], color='r')
sns.lineplot(data=y1['value'])
```

##### B) Define `x` and `y` parameters

```
sns.lineplot(data=y0, x=y0.index, y='value', color='r')
sns.lineplot(data=y1, x=y0.index, y='value')
```

Comment: Thank you! In my case the palette needed to be a tuple in order to work: `palette=("red",)`

Comment: `color`and `palette` are two different ways of operating with colors. Palette is a spectrum while color is a single static value.

Comment: Worth noting; you can also use hex codes as palette parameters