# Change color of seaborn lineplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a seaborn lineplot:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(22,14))
sns.lineplot(x="Datum", y="Value", ci=None, hue='Type', data=df)
plt.show()
```

Which leads to the following output:

[image]

How can i change the linecolors? For me the difference is hard to see.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing color of seaborn plot line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58432235/changing-color-of-seaborn-plot-line)

Comment: thx for the hint, but there its only for two lines, and i don't know how many lines i have in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change colors using `palettes`. Referring to https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html, try:

```python
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")
# Try playing with one set or another:
#sns.set_palette("husl")
sns.set_palette("PuBuGn_d")
ax = sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", hue="event", data=fmri)
```

you'll get different line colors, like this

[image]

or this

[image]

Answer (score 3):

At least in version 0.11.2 of seaborn, the lineplot function (`http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html`) has a parameter called *palette* that allows changing the color map used for the hue.

To check the available color maps you can refer to `https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html`

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")
#sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", hue="event", data=fmri, palette="tab10")
sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", hue="event", data=fmri, palette="Accent")
```

Comment: Still works in seaborn-0.13.2. It is more flexible to use a palette per plot, so +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use colour inside lineplot() method, however this, far as I know, works only with Series.
You can transform your data to Series with this this:

```
data = pd.Series(another_data)
```

Then plot Your data

```
sns.lineplot(..., data=data, color='red')
```

Another way is to use pallets

```
palette = sns.color_palette("mako_r", 6)
sns.lineplot(..., palette=palette, data=data)
```

More you can find in Seaborn lineplot reference: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html
Or here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58432483/12366487